# "stop face detection failed" exception when releasing the camera

Tags: android, face-detection

I'm using the new API 14+ [FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html) on a Galaxy Nexus to detect faces in a camera preview. Everything works fine and I can pick up faces, but when I try to shutdown the camera when the SurfaceHolder is destroyed I get a RuntimeException that says "stop face detection failed". The code I'm using to setup and stop the face detection looks like this:

```
public void surfaceChanged( SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h ) {
    if( isPreviewRunning ) {
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
    initPreview( w, h );
    camera.startPreview();
    if( enableFaceRecognition ) {
        camera.startFaceDetection();
    }
    isPreviewRunning = true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed( SurfaceHolder holder ) {
    if( camera != null ) {
        if( enableFaceRecognition ) {
            try {
                camera.stopFaceDetection();
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Huh?", e );
            }
        }
        cameraConfigured = false;
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

Oh and:

```
enableFaceRecognition = camera.getParameters().getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0
```

**Edit:**

Here's the logcat output:

```
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410): Huh?
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410): java.lang.RuntimeException: stop face detection failed
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.hardware.Camera._stopFaceDetection(Native Method)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.hardware.Camera.stopFaceDetection(Camera.java:1138)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at app.face.Preview.surfaceDestroyed(Preview.java:126)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:517)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:226)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:5839)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:965)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-31 18:59:47.809: E/Preview(9410):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas what's causing this exception?

Comment: Post the LogCat stack trace please.

Comment: Could be a dumb question but are you sure `surfaceChanged` is being reached? It's possible the error is because you haven't actually started face detection before you're trying to stop. I think that's unlikely but thought it was worth asking.

Comment: @Hbcdev Good question but no its definitely starting. Im getting face detection results in my listener.